# How to query nested value in AWS Cli?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

```
"MetricAlarms": [
    {
        "AlarmName": "AWS_CPUUtilisation_Alarm",
        "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
        "Statistic": "Average",
        "Dimensions": [
            {
                "Name": "InstanceId",
                "Value": "i-XXXXXXXXX"
            }
        ],
        "Period": 300,
        "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
    },
```

From the above data how can i get only instance id by using below command I am getting name and value:

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query "MetricAlarms[*].{Instanceid:Dimensions}" --output table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query "MetricAlarms[*].{Instanceid:Dimensions}[*].Instanceid[*].Value"
```

You might find it useful to play around with a tool like [jmespath terminal](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.terminal) or [jmespath tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html).

Comment: The [JMESPath Tutorial — JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) is excellent!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks John, I've added that to my answer